# Axis parallel cuboid with max area in an arbitrary ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I want to find the biggest axis parallel cuboid in an ellipsoid which may not be parallel to the axis.

The ellipsoid satisfies: $(X-X_0)^T\ A\ (X-X_0) + c < 0$,

where $X_0$ is the center of the ellipsoid. $A$ is the weighting matrix decides the shape and orientation of the ellipsoid. $c$ is a constant number.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it would be great if anyone can provide a general solution feasible to any dimensions.